# Why removing code duplication in const and non-const methods is not an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

I found two questions on stack overflow related to const_cast:

1) [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

2) [Is this undefined behavior with const_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209838/is-this-undefined-behavior-with-const-cast)

Let say we want to avoid code duplication like in answer for question 1:

```
struct C
{
  const char& get() const
  {
    return c;
  }
  char& get()
  {
    return const_cast<char&>(static_cast<const C&>(*this).get());
  }
  char c;
};
```

Let's use that class like that:

```
C obj;
obj.get() = 'a';
```

As I see we cast away a constness of `c` inside getter function and assign to its new value, so according to the second question, we should get undefined behavior.

Why assigning to `c` is not an undefined behavior?

Comment: Keep in mind that in the non-`const` overrload of `get` you know for a fact that `this` refers to a non-`const` instance of `C`.

Comment: But standard says that we can't modify objects after const_cast. (First answer of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406818/is-the-following-use-of-const-cast-undefined-behavior))

Comment: You can't modify a `const` object after `const_cast`. You certainly can if it isn't actually `const`. In the question you linked the `const int` is *actually* `const`. In your case you have a `const` reference to an actually non-`const` instance.

Comment: Do we have that in the standard?

Comment: The standard's section on [cv-qualifiers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.cv) (`const` and `volatile` qualifiers) has an example of a valid and of an invalid attempt at modifying a value through a `const_cast`.

Comment: Any code containing `const_cast` should *not* pass code review unless it comes with 10 times more comments explaining why than actual code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: True. But this is a very common pattern and will easily pass code review because it is a well known (and understood) common pattern.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. You are not modifying a const object. You simply have a const reference to a non-const object (which is also fine). Since you know (inside the non-cost get()) that your object is not const it is fine to cast away the const as it can't lead to UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is UB to modify a const object.

- `obj` is not declared `const`.
- `static_cast<const C&>(*this)` is *"just"* an alias.

So you are fine here.

Comment: @akulinich No, it's safe though suspicious looking.

Comment: `const C obj; const_cast<C&>(obj).get() = '*';` would be UB, with or without factorization. Meyers' solution won't introduce UB possibilities.