# Member access during period of destruction of (const) class objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, lifetime

Does the following program have UB if either of the commented lines is added?

```
#include<atomic>
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

std::atomic<bool> a = false;

struct T {
    int i;
    void reset() { i = 0; }
    ~T() {
        while(!a);
        //reset();
        a = false;
        while(!a);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::thread x;
    {
        const T t{42};
        x = std::thread([&t]{
            std::cout << t.i << "\n";
            a = true;
            while(a);
            //const_cast<T&>(t).reset();
            //const_cast<int&>(t.i) = 0;
            std::cout << t.i << "\n";
            a = true;
        });
    }
    x.join();
}
```

GCC prints `42` followed by `0`, while Clang prints `42` twice: https://godbolt.org/z/j544rq3cx

What if instead of using `t` directly in the thread, I captured a reference to `t.i` (synchronized before the destructor call begins) and both read and wrote through that reference? In that case no member access on `t` has to happen out-of-lifetime. Interestingly I can't manage to get Clang to print `42` twice with such a construct.

---

Intuitively I would have said UB already because `i` is accessed out-of-lifetime of `t` (which ends when the destructor is invoked), however at this point `t` is "under destruction" and different rules apply and I didn't find anything clearly stating UB.

Also, to avoid confusion, I do not believe that the `const` on `t` should have any impact on it being UB or not. However the `const` demonstrates that this has implications for compiler optimization as seen with how Clang handles it. Except during construction and destruction a `const` automatic storage duration object can't be modified, nor can the object be replaced, so compilers can usually assume that `i` won't change its value, even if a reference to `t` escapes to unknown functions.

Comment: [Is this undefined behavior with const_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209838/is-this-undefined-behavior-with-const-cast)

Comment: @DrewDormann The `const` object restrictions are lifted during the period of destruction: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#5

Comment: unless I'm missing something, the `const_cast<T&>(t)` in this code is not in a destructor.

Comment: @DrewDormann No, but it's under destruction. Nasty code :-)

Comment: @DrewDormann https://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#5.sentence-4 does not seem to apply only to the execution path through the destructor. But in any case, you can consider uncommenting just the first comment as well. That one goes through the destructor path.

Comment: The lifetime of an object ends when its destructor starts, which makes `t` a dangling reference immediately. It's too late to call `reset` on it.

Comment: I believe it's UB under **[basic.life]**. "The lifetime of an object `o` of type `T` ends when ...  the destructor call starts". "The properties ascribed to objects and references throughout this document apply for a given object or reference only during its lifetime." "In this subclause, “before” and “after” refer to the “happens before” relation" . The second `t.i` access doesn't *happen-before* the destructor call starts.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The lifetime of `t.i` however hasn't ended yet and I believe forming the expression `t.i` out-of-lifetime is still permitted. Even if not, I could have stored a reference to `t.i` before the lifetime ended and used that to access instead.

Comment: @user17732522 `t.i` doesn't just require `i` to be in its lifetime, it also requires `t` to be in its lifetime so the `t` part of the expression can be evaluated. Maybe you could make an argument if you took a reference to `t.i` ahead of time, at which point it becomes a lot less clear to me what happens. Edit : I suspect if a reference to an object is invalidated, references to its members are also invalidated separately from lifetime rules.

Comment: I think Igor and François has it. The `const` part of this question is a red herring.

Comment: @TedLyngmo To be fair I can't get Clang to print 42 twice with a direct reference to `i`, but I think that is mainly because the escape analysis can't work out the constness in that case. I don't think forming `t.i` is UB. Still, I have amended to question to incorporate that variation. The `const` is a red herring. I intentionally used it demonstrate why the question matters.

Comment: Curiously, **[class.cdtor]** says "During the construction of an object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor’s `this` pointer, the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified." But there's no symmetric rule for destruction. If there were, it'd cover `t.i` access, whether directly or through a previously captured reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes exactly. I assumed that there was a symmetric rule for destructors, but that's not the case, opening up the possibility to access member subobjects during destruction. I do not know whether or not that is intentional.

Comment: And there's another piece in **[class.cdtor]** that appears to suggest that accessing `t.i` should be OK: "To form a pointer to (or access the value of) a direct non-static member of an object `obj`, the construction of `obj` shall have started and its destruction shall not have completed, otherwise the computation of the pointer value (or accessing the member value) results in undefined behavior." This seems to say that it's OK to read a non-static data member through the end of destructor.